# Out of bounds exception error with String[][]

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

When trying to print out my 2 dimensional String array, I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:51)
```

This is my array:

```
String[][] list = {
    {"1",null},
    {"2",null},
    {"3",null},
    {"4",null},
    {"5",null},
    {"6",null},
    {"7",null},
    {"8",null},
    {"9",null},
    {"10",null},
    {"11",null},
    {"12",null},
    {"13",null},
    {"14",null},
    {"15",null}
};
```

And this is how I am printing it out:

```
for( int row=0; row<list.length; row++) {
    for( int col=0; col<list.length; col++) {
        System.out.print(list[row][col] + "\t"); //this is MainClass:java:51 where the error is happenin
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I am trying to print it out in a nice grid shape. The way I am doing it now DOES work for and Integr array so that's what has got me kind of confused.

Comment: Why are you initializing the second element of every row in your array with  null?

Comment: It's just a placeholder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`col<list.length` should be `col<list[row].length`